# Why is _GNU_SOURCE macro required for pthread_mutexattr_settype() while it is in POSIX/IEEE standard?

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, client-server, language-features

I have written a **multithread server program** in C, which echoes back all the data that a client sends.

Initially, I used `poll()` function in my program to detect `POLLRDHUP` event, for that I defined `_GNU_SOURCE` macro (This event is defined [here](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/poll.2.html)).

Later I updated my code & removed `poll()` function, however I forgot to remove `_GNU_SOURCE` macro.

Now my code is finally complete (and a little long to post, more than 250 lines). Before removing macro I was compiling my program using:

```c
gcc multi_thread_socket_v4.c -Wall -Werror -g -lpthread -o multi_thread_socket
```

and it worked fine: No errors, no warnings

**After I removed the macro definition**, and compiled using same command-line, the output of gcc was:

```
multi_thread_socket_v4.c: In function ‘main’:
multi_thread_socket_v4.c:194: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pthread_mutexattr_settype’
multi_thread_socket_v4.c:194: error: ‘PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
multi_thread_socket_v4.c:194: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
multi_thread_socket_v4.c:194: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

I have **included all the required libraries** as it worked fine initially.

I peeked into `pthread.h` at `/usr/include/pthread.h` and found out this:

```c
/* Mutex types.  */
enum
{
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_TIMED_NP,
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE_NP,
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK_NP,
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_ADAPTIVE_NP
#ifdef __USE_UNIX98
  ,
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL = PTHREAD_MUTEX_TIMED_NP,
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE = PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE_NP,
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK = PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK_NP,
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT = PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL
#endif
#ifdef __USE_GNU
  /* For compatibility.  */
  , PTHREAD_MUTEX_FAST_NP = PTHREAD_MUTEX_TIMED_NP
#endif
};
```

and this:

```c
#ifdef __USE_UNIX98
/* Return in *KIND the mutex kind attribute in *ATTR.  */
extern int pthread_mutexattr_gettype (__const pthread_mutexattr_t *__restrict
                      __attr, int *__restrict __kind)
     __THROW __nonnull ((1, 2));

/* Set the mutex kind attribute in *ATTR to KIND (either PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL,
   PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK, or
   PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT).  */
extern int pthread_mutexattr_settype (pthread_mutexattr_t *__attr, int __kind)
     __THROW __nonnull ((1));
```

I [checked out here](http://linux.die.net/man/7/feature_test_macros) to check if `__USE_UNIX98` is a feature test macro, but it was not there.

So please **help me understanding the reasons for the error,** because **the function & the macro where `gcc` shows error [are defined in POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_gettype.html)**. I do not know what more info regarding my problem will be required so please tell me, I will update my question.

Comment: The most obvious answer is that the feature is not in Posix, but only in Linux. By default, the pthread library tries to be Posix conforming.

Comment: Also note that double-underscore macros aren't for you to use; they're reset internally. You can only use top-level macros like `_GNU_SOURCE` and `_BSD_SOURCE` to control which parts of the library are pulled in.

Comment: @KerrekSB : But the function `pthread_setattr_settype()` & the macro `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK` are [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_gettype.html), so why they need `_GNU_SOURCE` to be defined?

Comment: But they aren't standard C, so they need *something* to be defined ... not necessarily _GNU_SOURCE, which is a kitchen sink define that drags in lots of stuff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
```

if you want to use POSIX features such as pthread_mutexattr_settype ... see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/xsh_chap02_02.html

Another possibility is

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
```

See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html and http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Setting _GNU_SOURCE includes POSIX and lots of other definitions.

P.S. I would expect that including `<pthread.h>` includes `<features.h>`, which by default defines _POSIX_C_SOURCE as 200112L, but it's possible that you have defined something that overrides that ... see /usr/include/features.h on your system for details of the symbols and their usage.

Comment: Got your point, will read them. By the way [this link I found](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap02.html) is more recent standard revision.

Comment: @nishant That link is within the one I gave. I don't really think you need to read them, you just need to provide the defines. What I'm doing here is answering your question.

Comment: Thanks, although `_XOPEN_SOURCE 700` did the trick (so did the `_GNU_SOURCE`). but won't it affect other functions also? I mean may be other functions start behaving differently.

Comment: @nishant Mostly it affects what symbols are visible, not behavior. You could get behavior changes if you were explicitly asking for older obsolescent versions of standards.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't, your problem likely lies elsewhere.

I just compiled a trivial program with the following content:

```
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_mutexattr_t attr;

    pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK);

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles perfectly with `gcc -pthread -Wall -Werror a.c`.

It's possible that another part of your program causes this, by eg. doing something silly like defining `_PTHREAD_H`, or some other minor sabotage.

You might want to try to get a minimal test case by using a tool like [delta](http://delta.tigris.org/) or [creduce](http://embed.cs.utah.edu/creduce/), which will probably make the problem evident.

Comment: Your code gives same error on my machine. 

Machine specs: 
Operating System: SLES 10 SP3 x86-64.

Comment: @nishant There are other answers here. Try mine.

Comment: @nishant: That's quite strange. I've built this on a vanilla debian install. AFAIK, you shouldn't have to explicitly define any feature macros, as `features.h` included from `pthread.h` should define these if nothing else was defined (which is why this compiles here, which I just checked using `gcc -E -fdirectives-only`.)

Comment: I'll also note that setting some things will break this, eg. defining `__STRICT_ANSI__ ` (by way of the `-ansi` flag), or `_POSIX_SOURCE` or  `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`. (in my case, this ends up setting `__USE_XOPEN2K8` which enables the function)

Comment: I studied the output of `gcc file.c -E -fdirectives-only` but nowhere there, `__USE_UNIX98` was defined. However after `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` this line `#define __USE_UNIX98` was there at the end.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using **old** libraries (e.g. 2.1.x) you should use

```
#define __USE_UNIX98
```

Using a macro beginning with "__" it's not usually a good idea, but sometimes it's the only way... see also [this discussion](https://sourceware.org/ml/glibc-linux/1999-q3/msg00006.html)